# customizing chosen jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have implemented a multiple select using the jquery chosen plugin. Its works fine.

Now consider the select box contains the following values:

- one
- one two
- one three
- two
- two three

If I type 'two', the result is displayed like below,

- one two
- two
- two three

But I need to customize it so the matching results containing the characters at the beginning should show first:

- two
- two three
- one two

Sample HTML Below:

> ```
> <select class="chosen" data-order="true" name="multiselect[]" id="multiselect" multiple="true">
>     <option value="1">one</option>
>     <option value="12">one two</option>
>     <option value="13">one three</option>
>     <option value="2">two</option>
>     <option value="23">two three</option>
> </select>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>      $(".chosen").chosen({
>     disable_search_threshold: 10,
>     no_results_text: "No Results Found!",
>     width: "50%"
>   });
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of trials and errors, I came up with this idea . Its working as per requirement . Try it

```js
$(function() {

  // run chosen plugin
  $("#my-dropdown").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    no_results_text: "No Results Found!",
    width: "50%"
  });

  $(".default").keyup(function() {

    $(".chosen-results li").sort(sort_bey).appendTo('.chosen-results');

    function sort_bey(a, b) {

      var str = $(a).text();

      var str2 = $(b).text();

      var v = $('.default').val();

      var p1 = str.indexOf(v.charAt(0));

      var p2 = str2.indexOf(v.charAt(0));

      return (p1 > p2) ? 1 : -1;
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<select class="chosen" data-order="true" name="multiselect[]" id="my-dropdown" multiple="true">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="12">one two</option>
  <option value="13">one three</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="23">two three</option>
</select>
```